# How do I obtain for each distinct primary key occurrence in a table, the first of an ordered set of rows?

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, informix, distinct

I want to obtain a specific set of results from a table **in a single query** and I'm not being able to find how to do it.

I've a got a table recording every agent state change (online, offline, away, etc) and the time when it happened.

I want to obtain **for each agent id the last state change**, i.e. considering agents A and B, I'd have the original table containing:

**ID | STATE | DATETIME**

A | Online | 29-11-2010

A | Offline | 30-11-2010

B | Away | 28-11-2010

B | Online | 30-11-2010

And I would want to generate an output like so:

**ID | STATE | DATETIME**

A | Offline | 30-11-2010

B | Online | 30-11-2010

I realize this might be a really basic select query, but I can't put my finger on what my be. Also mad props if it could be INFORMIX compatible :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
SELECT datetime, id, state FROM table t1 
 WHERE t1.datetime = (SELECT MAX(t2.datetime) FROM table t2 WHERE t2.id=t1.id)
```

Comment: Exactly what I was about to answer. @LostKaleb: On another note, I would suggest to avoid keywords as column names. It hurts my eyes :)

Comment: That seems to do the trick! Thanks loads, been stuck here for a while and, as I thought, there was a simple yet elusive solution! :D